# .delay() only works on first animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

I have written a simple jQuery fade plugin but I am having trouble getting the delay to work correctly.  It will work on the first item but then it is ignored after that

**jQuery**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.setupQuoteFade = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            fadeSpeed: 600,
            fadeDelay: 5000
        }, options);

        return $(this).each(function () {
            var quoteHolder = $(this),
                quotes = quoteHolder.children('p'),
                fadeIndex = 0;

            fade();

            function fade() {
                quotes.eq(fadeIndex)
                    .stop()
                    .delay(options.fadeDelay)
                    .animate({ opacity: 0 }, options.fadeSpeed, function () {
                        fadeIndex++;
                        if (fadeIndex == quotes.length) {
                            fadeIndex = 0;
                        }

                        quotes.eq(fadeIndex).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, options.fadeSpeed, function () {
                            fade();
                        });
                    });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5v3FT/)

As you can see from the example, it waits 5 seconds before starting the animation to fadeout but then each call after that happens immediately rather than waiting the 5 seconds.

I have tried adding things like `.clearQueue()` in various places or `queue: true` to the animation options - in the case of the later it stops the fading of the second item happening.

I know I can use a `setTimeout` on the fade function but I'm trying to understand why the `.delay()` doesn't work

**Edit**

Further to Dominik's comments, by removing the `.stop()` it allows the [plugin to work](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/StF6f/1/) correctly so having read about stop, I thought you are able to pass in a boolean to tell it to clear the queue and therefore allow the delay to work properly - eg `.stop(true).delay(5000)`, but it doesn't.

So I guess the question is what in `.stop()` is stopping the `.delay()` from working and how would I be able to make them work together (for future reference as I may need to use a delay with a stop for hover animations)

Comment: just a quick thought, not an answer: seems to have something to do with fadespeed. setting this to 5000 either, it looks more like what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Dominik I have a solution for this using setTimeout but I'm just wanting to know why delay doesn't work rather than have a workaround

Comment: hum, i know that. was just a thought which could perhaps bring someone to the right answer... btw, another one: removing the two stop()-calls inside your fade-method and adding delay(options.fadeDelay) before second "animate" in complete-handler results in  the expected behaviour (as I understand it). just did a lil trial and error => http://jsfiddle.net/StF6f/

Comment: @Dominik ah, i think you're onto something there - if you just remove the stop [it will work properly](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/StF6f/1/), I wonder if `.stop()` removes the queueing functionality and therefore that's why delay doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to implement delays with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) javascript function. Instead of just calling fade(), call setTimeout and pass *fade()* and *options.fadeDelay* as arguments. Here is an example:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.setupQuoteFade = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      fadeSpeed: 600,
      fadeDelay: 5000
    }, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {
      var quoteHolder = $(this),
        quotes = quoteHolder.children('p'),
        fadeIndex = 0;

      fade();

      function fade() {
        quotes.eq(fadeIndex)
          .stop()
          .delay(options.fadeDelay)
          .animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, options.fadeSpeed, function() {
            fadeIndex++;
            if (fadeIndex == quotes.length) {
              fadeIndex = 0;
            }

            quotes.eq(fadeIndex).stop().animate({
              opacity: 1
            }, options.fadeSpeed, function() {
              fade();
            });
          });
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#quote-holder').setupQuoteFade();
```

```css
#quote-holder {
  position: relative;
}

#quote-holder>p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#quote-holder>p:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote-holder">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent purus risus, tincidunt nec ante eget, aliquet dapibus nunc. </p>
  <p>Nullam faucibus odio non semper auctor. Mauris porttitor quam vel volutpat malesuada. Nullam sed consequat libero. Fusce ut dolor lorem.</p>
  <p>Vestibulum ut justo in tortor commodo vulputate. Donec imperdiet dolor urna, eget imperdiet arcu tincidunt at. Praesent egestas a leo nec tincidunt. </p>
  <p>Proin eu quam viverra, varius velit eu, ultrices lorem. Aliquam feugiat sapien ac quam luctus pharetra. Pellentesque ut dignissim sem.</p>
  <p>Proin ac tellus nec enim dapibus fermentum. Integer et metus lectus. Sed ut odio in libero sagittis pretium ultricies in nisl. </p>
  <p>In tellus diam, gravida quis turpis ut, tincidunt tempus lectus. Vestibulum dignissim consectetur nisi suscipit aliquet. Nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>
```

```
setTimeout(fade, options.fadeDelay);
```

Hope this helps!

**upd:** oops, sorry. didn't see your remarks about setTimeout in description.